# Is List::Util changing the representation of my number?

Tags: perl, module

This is the end part of a script that takes 4 days information,
averages the previous three days, then subtracts todays value from the average
to get the variance.

The first example is correct.
However the second example if you subtract 0.00299268 from 0.002997575 equals -0.000004895. However [`List::Util`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aUtil) is listing it as  -4.89499999999955e-06.

I need to get it in regular notation.

```
use List::Util qw/sum/;
$todays_latency = $ecp_average[0];
$sum = sum $ecp_average[1] + $ecp_average[2] + $ecp_average[3]  + $ecp_average[4];

$average = $sum/$#ecp_average;
$variance = $todays_latency - $average ;

print "Todays listing is  $todays_latency\n";
print "The Average is $average\n";
print "Todays Variance from the average is $variance\n";
print "\n";

foreach(@ecp_average){

    print "$_\n";
}

print "\n";
 @ecp_average = ();
}
```

#### Output

```
Eislnd1
Todays listing is  0.00376258
The Average is 0.004412365
Todays Variance from the average is -0.000649785
0.00376258
0.00371207
0.00511266

Eislnd2
Todays listing is  0.00299268
The Average is 0.002997575
Todays Variance from the average is -4.89499999999955e-06
0.00299268
0.00301986
0.00297529
```

Comment: Your text says average 3 days, but your code averages 4 days! You seem to expect that @ecp_average contains 5 values, but your output shows only 3 values! Your problem does not have anything to do with List::Util.

Comment: Also, your code has unbalanced parentheses, and variables that aren't initialized before they're used. Post an entire (runnable) code sample or else we can't really identify where the problem may be.

Comment: Yeah, it is desigend to run just on friday for now, and i worked on this a few days before i posted it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a <strike>rounding</strike> numerical representation issue.

From [`perldoc perlfaq4 :` Why am I getting long decimals (eg, 19.9499999999999) instead of the numbers I should be getting (eg, 19.95)?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#Why-am-I-getting-long-decimals-%28eg%2c-19.9499999999999%29-instead-of-the-numbers-I-should-be-getting-%28eg%2c-19.95%29%3f) :

---

> For the long explanation, see David Goldberg's "What Every Computer
>   Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic"
>   (http://web.cse.msu.edu/~cse320/Documents/FloatingPoint.pdf).
>
> Internally, your computer represents floating-point numbers in binary.
>   Digital (as in powers of two) computers cannot store all numbers
>   exactly. Some real numbers lose precision in the process. This is a
>   problem with how computers store numbers and affects all computer
>   languages, not just Perl.
>
> [`perlnumber`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlnumber.html) shows the gory details of number
>   representations and conversions. To limit the number of decimal places
>   in your numbers, you can use the [`printf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html) or [`sprintf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) function.
>
> See Floating Point Arithmetic in [`perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) for more details.
>
> ```
> printf "%.2f", 10/3;
> my $number = sprintf "%.2f", 10/3;
> ```

---

In other words, if this is an issue, round it using `sprintf`:

```
$variance = sprintf '%.9f', $todays_latency - $average ;  # Rounded to 9 d.p.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
printf "Todays Variance from the average is %.9f\n", $variance;
```

Answer (score 1):

By the way,

```
my $sum = sum $ecp_average[1] + $ecp_average[2] +
              $ecp_average[3] + $ecp_average[4];
```

makes no sense. You are only passing one number to `sum`, so it's effectively a no-op. You want

```
my $sum = $ecp_average[1] + $ecp_average[2] +
          $ecp_average[3] + $ecp_average[4];
```

or

```
my $sum = sum @ecp_average[1..4];
```

[This should really be a comment, but it wouldn't be legible as a comment. Please pardon the placement.]